# Applying the DRY principle to this jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code:

```
var thumb = $($('#slider').children('.ui-slider-handle'));   
setLabelPosition();    

$('#slider').bind('slide', function (event, ui) {   
    $('#boksTimer').html((((ui.value) / 31) * 60).toFixed(0) + ' min pr. dag');
    setLabelPosition();
});


    function setLabelPosition() {
    var label = $('#boksTimer');
    label.css('top', '10px');
    label.css('left', thumb.position().left - (label.width() - thumb.width())/ 2);        
}


var thumb2 = $($('#slider2').children('.ui-slider-handle'));   
setLabelPosition2();    

$('#slider2').bind('slide', function (event, ui) {   
    $('#boksTimer2').html((((ui.value) / 31) * 60).toFixed(0) + ' min pr. dag');
    setLabelPosition2();
});


    function setLabelPosition2() {
    var label2 = $('#boksTimer2');
    label.css('top', '10px');
    label.css('left', thumb2.position().left - (label2.width() - thumb2.width())/ 2);        
}


var thumb3 = $($('#slider3').children('.ui-slider-handle'));   
setLabelPosition3();    

$('#slider3').bind('slide', function (event, ui) {   
    $('#boksTimer3').html((((ui.value) / 31) * 60).toFixed(0) + ' min pr. dag');
    setLabelPosition3();
});


    function setLabelPosition3() {
    var label3 = $('#boksTimer3');
    label.css('top', '10px');
    label.css('left', thumb3.position().left - (label3.width() - thumb3.width())/ 2);        
}
```

How can I make it more DRY?

DRY = Don't repeat yourself

Comment: This smells like a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ...

Comment: I just have a bunch of sliders like this: http://jsfiddle.net/z3xV3/50/ 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the easiest way I can think of:

```
$('#slider, #slider2, #slider3').bind('slide', function (event, ui)
{
    var num = this.id.replace('slider',''),
        $label = $('#boksTimer' + num).html( (ui.value / 31 * 60).toFixed(0) + ' min pr. dag' ),
        $thumb = $(this).children('.ui-slider-handle');

    $label.css({
        top: 10,
        left: $thumb.position().left - ( $label.width() - $thumb.width() ) / 2
    });
});
```

That said, you should look into modifying your code to use classes.

Comment: @Railsbeginner - I don't understand what you're trying to say. The code I posted should work for all the sliders.

Comment: Your `this.id.slice(-1)` won't work on the ID that doesn't end with a number. You could do `var num = this.id.replace('slider','');`

Comment: @amnotiam - That's why I had used `parseInt`, so that I'm sure that it's a number; but I forgot that I'll get `NaN`. I updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I have made a JSfiddle has you can see the first boxTimer is not showing and none of them are following the handler position. http://jsfiddle.net/z3xV3/58/

Comment: @Railsbeginner, the first boxTimer is not showing because in the DOM the id is 'slider1' but it must be 'slider' according to your script. http://jsfiddle.net/z3xV3/63/

Comment: It works. http://jsfiddle.net/z3xV3/62/ What is the best way dealing with different calculations and boxTimer text?

Comment: I do I create if #slider1 then $label = $('#boksTimer' + num).html( (ui.value / 31 * 60).toFixed(0) + ' min pr. dag' ) if #slider2 $label = $('#boksTimer' + num).html( (ui.value / 31 ).toFixed(0) + ' min pr. dag' ) etc?

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you could set parameters in your functions - to pass in arguments - instead of just making two of the same functions with different names.

```
function setLabelPosition(element) {        
    var label = $(element);
    label.css('top', '10px');
    label.css('left', thumb.position().left - (label.width() - thumb.width())/ 2);        
}
```

But I have to say you would probably get a lot more useful advice if you posted this on the code review section of stackexchange:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Javascript in your site can grow and grow until it just becomes a tangled mess.  You should also look into using an organizational framework like Backbone.js, Knockout.js, Sproutcore, or Dojo.

They all have the capacity to help you organize your javascript into Models and Views.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the data from the code. Create "Configuration Objects" that could be dictionaries such as:

```
// not using javascript syntax but just describing the concept

cfg1={'name':'slider1', 'timerName':'boksTimer2',}
cfg2={'name':'slider3', 'timerName':'boksTimer3',}

function renderCfg(cfg) {

// use different cfgs here to do whatever you want

}
```

Comment: Do put an explanation for down-voting whoever did that. Doesn't help the poster or anyone to not know the reason

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the entire block of code with this:

```
 function bindSlider(slider, boks) {
    var boks$ = $(boks), slider$ = $(slider), thumb$ = slider$.children('.ui-slider-handle'); 
    slider$.bind('slide', function (event, ui) {   
        boks$.html((((ui.value) / 31) * 60).toFixed(0) + ' min pr. dag')
            .css({'top': '10px', 'left', thumb$.position().left - (boks$.width() - boks$.width())/ 2});
    });
}

bindSlider('#slider', '#boksTimer');
bindSlider('#slider2', '#boksTimer2');
bindSlider('#slider3', '#boksTimer3');
```

Or, even more succinctly like this:

```
$('#slider, #slider2, #slider3').bind('slide', function (event, ui) {   
    var boks$ = $("#boksTimer" + this.id.replace("slider", ""));
    boks$.html((((ui.value) / 31) * 60).toFixed(0) + ' min pr. dag')
        .css({'top': '10px', 'left', $(this).children('.ui-slider-handle').position().left - (boks$.width() - boks$.width())/ 2});
});
```